# How to apply css to a specific item id within a container with specific Id using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three containers with different Ids but similar content with similar ids, one is books, the others pens and pencils.

How do i apply a style to an item when it is clicked under each of these containers with their ids?

```
<div id="Books">
<div id="1">Stack</div>
<div id="2">Flow</div>
</div>

<div id="Pens">
<div id="1">big</div>
<div id="2">small</div>
</div>

<div id="Pencils">
<div id="1">big</div>
<div id="2">small</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to do with that?

Comment: You should disambiguate your IDs to be unique within a document, which would neatly eliminate your problem. If you need to address multiple elements that share a given role, CSS classes are the way to go.

Comment: can you give all container divs a class (can you modify your HTML)?

Comment: Where is the CSS? The JS?

Comment: thanks @collapsar this solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disambiguate your IDs to be unique within a document, which would neatly eliminate your problem. If you need to address multiple elements that share a given role, CSS classes are the way to go.

As stated in the comment section by @collapsar

Answer (score 0):

Follows a full working solution using [vanilla javascript](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```js
function clicked(element) {
  element.classList.add('success')
}
```

```css
.success {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Books">
<div id="1" onclick="clicked(this)">Stack</div>
<div id="2" onclick="clicked(this)">Flow</div>
</div>

<div id="Pens">
<div id="1" onclick="clicked(this)">big</div>
<div id="2" onclick="clicked(this)">small</div>
</div>

<div id="Pencils">
<div id="1" onclick="clicked(this)">big</div>
<div id="2" onclick="clicked(this)">small</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens after several user clicks in a row? The classes are never reset so the code will highlight mutually exclusive items.

Answer (score -1):

Find the below answer with jquery

```
$('#Books').click(()=>{
 $(this).find('#1').css('background-color', 'red');
 $(this).find('#2').css('background-color', 'blue');
})

$('#Pens').click(()=>{
 $(this).find('#1').css('background-color', 'red');
 $(this).find('#2').css('background-color', 'blue');
})

$('#Pencils').click(()=>{
 $(this).find('#1').css('background-color', 'red');
 $(this).find('#2').css('background-color', 'blue');
})
```